How can i implement a tab selector for BottomNavigationView?
Hellow there,
i just wanna implement a tab selector for BottomNavigation view like this:

At the moment i don't care about the item animations, i only want to put the bottom rectangle for the selected items, how can i reach that
I have tried a multiple options and configurations, but i didn't found a simple solution for this problem that doesn't requires an external library implementation.

I solved it by myself, I put it in case it can help someone:
U need to create a drawable like that @drawable/bottom_nav_active_indicator:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <size android:height="80dp" android:width="80dp"/>
                    <solid android:color="@color/canary_gray" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:top="65dp" android:bottom="12dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <size android:height="4dp" android:width="20dp"/>
                    <solid android:color="@color/canary_yellow" />
                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>

Then u just need to use it here:
app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_nav_active_indicator"

That worked for me:

